# The way to show mouse cursor using selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I tried to click on chrome browser while using ActionChains.

> `from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains`

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get(URL)
link = driver.find_element_by_id('link')
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.double_click(advanced_options_link).perform()
```

But what is more?!
I want to see mouse cursor on browser to monitor what is exactly happening.
*** Please help ***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to use a function like this in the past. as far as Iv'e researched I learned that it's not possible with selenium. you can hover on elements or even move the cursor to a specific location on the scree, but you can't see it moving because it's not really moving the cursor, selenium dose not have control over the cursor in that fashion.

You can try to research this, you might be able to use something outside selenium to control the actual cursor of the computer. but, even if it's possible it will still be very hard to get it to work reliably because you don't have the control on the website that you have with selenium so everything becomes manual, therefore hard and keen to generate errors.

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in option in `selenium` to show cursor created by action. But you can use below script to add a `div` inside the DOM when the test is ongoing, which will show a dot when the click is performed.

```
cursor_script = '''
var cursor = document.createElement('div');
cursor.style.position = 'absolute';
cursor.style.zIndex = '9999';
cursor.style.width = '10px';
cursor.style.height = '10px';
cursor.style.borderRadius = '50%';
cursor.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
cursor.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
document.body.appendChild(cursor);

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  cursor.style.left = e.pageX - 5 + 'px';
  cursor.style.top = e.pageY - 5 + 'px';
});
'''

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://example.com')

driver.execute_script(cursor_script)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Does it work if you try using the `move_to_element()` from `ActionChains`? something like this;

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(URL)
link = driver.find_element_by_id('link')

hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(link)
hover.perform()
```